# how do i start the LWUIT resource editor in linux system?

Tags: linux, lwuit, netbeans-7, lwuit-resource-editor

i am trying to explore LWUIT using NetBeans 7.2 
I am working on Linux Machine.
After a week working with LWUIT, I got to know about  LWUIT Designer or known as LWUIT Resource Editor.... But i am not getting how to install / run it on my linux system.

Kindly help regarding this

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a J2ME simulator such as the WTK. Most aren't available for Linux and only work on Windows there might be an old version of the WTK that might work on Linux.

Alternatively you can use [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/), which is developed by the authors of LWUIT (myself included) and doesn't require all that hassle (works on Linux seamlessly).